# Time series forecasting

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I have an input and target series. However, the target series lags 3 steps behind the input. Can I still use narx or some other network?

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/nnet/ref/narxnet.html

```
Predict: y(t+1)
Input:
x(t)  |?
x(t-1)|?
x(t-2)|?
x(t-3)|y(t-3)
x(t-4)|y(t-4)
x(t-5)|y(t-5)
...
```

During my training, I have y(t-2), y(t-1), y(t) in advance, but when I do the prediction in real life, those values are only available 3 steps later, because I calculate y from the next 3 inputs.

Comment: I would guess that yes, you just predict y(t-2) based on what you have, then y(t-1) using y(t-2) and then y(t) using t(t-1). But I've never actually used an autoregressive NN.

Comment: Actually looking at the documentation it sounds like `feedbackDelays` should let you do this? Maybe try it with something simple like a linear dataset to check whether it is predicting what you expect.

Comment: @Richante I could convert it to a closed loop network, so it feeds back its own predictions, but in this case how could I replace the predicted y with the real y once it becomes available? So that after 3 steps the network doesn't calculate with its own predictions anymore, but with the real targets, which should increase its accuracy I guess...

Comment: ah, not sure. I guess as a messy solution you could copy the whole net structure before predicting, and then use one version to predict and the other one to train on the next data point. But it sounds like your task is what narxnet is designed for, so there must be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options

1) Also, you could have two inputs and one output as

x(t),  y(t-3) -> y(t)

x(t-1),y(t-4) -> y(t-1)

x(t-2),y(t-5) -> y(t-2)
...

and predict the single output y(t)

2) You could also use ar or arx with na = 0, nb > 0, and nk = 3.

3) Also, you could have four inputs, where 2 of the inputs are estimated and one output as

x(t),  y(t-3), ye(t-2),  ye(t-1) -> y(t)

x(t-1),y(t-4),  y(t-3),  ye(t-2) -> y(t-1)

x(t-2),y(t-5),  y(t-4),   y(t-3) -> y(t-2)
...

and predict the single output y(t), using line 3 and higher as training data

4) You could setup the input/output as in steps one or three and use s4sid

I have a similar problem, but without any measurable inputs.  And I'm trying to see how much error there is as the forecast distance and model complexity are increased.  But I've only tried approach 2 and set nb = 5 to 15 by 5 and varied nk from 20 to 150 by 10 and plotted contours of maximum error.  In my case, I'm not interested in predictions of less than 20 time steps.

Answer (score 0):

Define a window of your choice( you need to try different sizes to see which is the best value). Now make this problem a regression problem. Use values of xt and yt from t=T-2... T-x where x-2 is the size of window. Now use regress() to train a regression model and use it for  prediction.